# calculating speaker inductive

Tags: audio, impedance, impedance-matching, lm386

I am using an 8ohm ,0.5w speaker [like this BMS16-16](http://www.bestartech.com/documents/PDFs/BMS1611C08H4.3RP%20LF.PDF) .
I also have [LM386](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) which suggest to use a 10 ohm resistor in seris with a 0.05micro capcitor .I am trying to understand how this together is suppose to be 8 ohm or what is the inductive of the speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speaker impedance might be around 3~4 Ω at DC.
When tested at 2Khz moving air, the inductive higher impedance is shunted by the air pressure load ( real impedance ) and rated at 8 Ohms at 0.5W

The Series RC circuit is shunted across many push-pull amps to provide a "dummy Load" above audio frequencies, which is essential for loop stability to prevent ultrasonic oscillations that run full power saturated and cause problems.  This circuit prevents this.  The reason is that the driver output impedance rises with frequency as a LPF effect and this combined causes a phase shift in signal feedback that leads to instability. The 10Ω shunt prevents this and the 0.05uF makes sure it only happens above the audio band.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. A Zobel network. Source: [Wavecor](http://www.wavecor.com/html/zobel_networks.html).*

You are describing a Zobel network. From the article linked in Figure 1:

> In some speaker designs it is an advantage to use a so called Zobel network (figure on the right) to linearize the impedance of a drive unit.
>   The effect of a correctly designed Zobel network is shown below on the impedance curve.
>   Whether to use a separate network to equalize the high frequency impedance will depend on the crossover topology used, on personal design preferences, etc.
>
> A Zobel network is a series resistor-capacitor (Req-Ceq) network that is connected in parallel with a loudspeaker driver in order to neutralize the effects of the driver’s voice coil inductance Le (see note below about Le).
>   If a Zobel, or other kinds of networks, are used for driver impedance linearization/modification, it is important that the network be connected right on the driver terminals, between the driver and the crossover.

[image]

*Figure 2. Frequency response modification without and with Zobel network.*

Comment: @Transitor yes its a boucheret cell. but I want to do the calculation by myself.
if I assume the speaker is moudled as 8ohm resistor + 0.005 mh inductor then I can say that using 10ohm resitor + 0.05 micro capcitor is correct , but I can't find anything that will justify these calcualtion

Comment: OK, I can't help you then.

Comment: http://www.bonavolta.ch/hobby/images/audio/zobel.gif
you think this calculation is right?